# Get Thunderbird email contents to show up in Windows 10/11 search

Tags: windows-10, thunderbird, windows-search, search-indexing

Has anyone successfully gotten the content of Thunderbird emails to show up in Windows 10/11 search?

I have Enable Global Search and Indexer checked in Thunderbird settings and I have the Manage Store Type for new accounts set to File per folder.

If not, can anyone recommend a 3rd party tool?

This worked great in Windows 7 and I just upgraded to Windows 11

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To add Thunderbird mail **local folders**, [add the Thunderbird profile to Windows Search](https://winaero.com/add-folders-search-index-windows-10/):

- Press <kbd>Windows</kbd>, type *search*, and select *Change how Windows searches*.
- Press *Modify* button.
- Navigate to the folders that are used to store mail messages, e.g., `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Thunderbird\Profiles\<profilefolder>.default`, and add *Mail* and *ImapMail* folders. It is the *.wdseml* files in those folders that contain the mesages, and the contents need to be indexed.
  *Enable Windows Search to index the messages.

  - Open Thunderbird *Preferences*
  - In the box at the upper-right, enter *search*.
  - Click on *Enable Global Search and Indexer*.

[image: Enable mail indexing]

Of course, this only work on local folders, where mail has been downloaded. **N.B.** to allow indexing, Thunderbird must *save the contents unencrypted*. To some extent, that is a security hazard. On a machine kept at home, perhaps with drive encrypted, it might be considered negligible, but it in a corporate environment, it might be an issue.

If you prefer [DocFetcher's](http://docfetcher.sourceforge.net/) indexing, add indexes for *Mail* and *ImapMail* folders as above. Note that *DocFetcher* requires Java also be installed.

Comment: Which file types are actually searched by Windows Indexing? I am wondering if this is perhaps an issue of the wdseml file type needing to be indexed "with content" - it was set to Properties Only. I've already got the Profile folder added but my data directory is not in appdata - I moved it to a location which is also indexed.

Comment: I should have said, which file type are NECESSARY for mail indexing. I know from the file type list which ones are indexed. I know the MBOX files have no extension and have the actual messages (but are not indexed by Windows Search). The MSF files are an index (I believe) into the MBOX files - and are indexed by Windows Search as File Properties Filter. The WDSEML files appear to be a plain text version used for indexing - and are also indexed by Windows Search as File Properties Filter. The folders for all these files are included in Windows Search Include for Indexing Options.

Comment: @mseifert, yes, it is indeed the *.wdseml* files that contain the email, and the *contents* need to be indexed. That will be added to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The official method is:

- Open Thunderbird menu *Tools > Preferences*
- Go to the General section
- Under "System Integration", place a check-mark on
  "Allow Windows Search to search messages".

The
[Search - Thunderbird](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Search_-_Thunderbird)
says this:

> If you have a desktop search engine installed such as Recoll (Linux) , Everything (Windows) or Alfred (OS X) it can also search downloaded messages in your profile. Thunderbird defaults to using the `mbox` format to store messages. That is widely supported. You can also configure an account to use the maildir format. That stores messages in individual files using the `.eml` format, though they have no file extension. Many desktop search engines will have problems with Thunderbird's version of maildir.